# Online refund not working

Tags: magento-1.9, refund

We updated our Magento version a couple weeks ago to the 1.9.2.4 (CE) version. This week we tried to create some online refunds and it was not working. (I tried with multiple different orders, so I am pretty sure was not a specific situation).

I know that my payment gateway (Authorize.NET) accepts online refunds because we always worked with refunds using Magento. I contact them to see if anything has changed in their end but they said that there is no changes in the refund process.

I am not sure if this is related to the update that I made in the Magento version or if could be any other problem.

Any ideas on how to troubleshot this? Or any similar experiences? I have no clue on how to fix this...

Comment: It sounds to me like a problem with the module you are using to accept the payments. You will have to contact the author for support.

Comment: From which version you upgrade?

Comment: Hi @SR_Magento, what you mean by "module to accept payments"? I am using the methods that come with Magento: PayPal and Authorize.NET...

Comment: @SohelRana, I updated from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2

Comment: As my memory with Authorize go you can do refund only after payment is settled. If you try to do it eariler it won't work. Authorize performs this once a day.

Comment: Thanks! You are right on that @Zefiryn, but in my case, even after the payment is settled, refund still not working.

Comment: are there any errors in system.log or exceptions.log? Did you get any errors on the Admin side? Which version did you update from?

Comment: Hi @KalvinKlien, I updated from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2.4. There is no error on the log or the admin side. It just don't show the online refund option button. So I can't even "try" to do the refund...

Comment: hmmm...are you using a custom plugin for Authorize.net? If not, check magento connector to see if there is a new standard magento plugin out for it. Maybe there is some kind of update. Double-check your Authorize.net settings and definitely do a test order to see if you get charged or not. Otherwise just do a manual/offline refund if that is available.

Comment: Yeah, that is super weird. My website is working fine, I can place orders and the process works great. I am not using any plugin for Authorize.NET and there is no update available...but thanks.

Comment: I know that could be many things, and that's why is hard for me to discover at least the direction I should go to troubleshoot it. I tried everything I could think and nothing seems to work or give me a clue...

Comment: check at least 5-10 orders that were made. Maybe there is something wrong with the order status and it doesnt allow you to do refunds on that specific status / state.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tested that with 15 orders from different customers, different products, shipping methods, etc...none of them worked :(

Comment: is there refund offline option present when you do credit memo? You probably need to have a developer to take a look at it. There must be error logs showing something wrong when you go to credit memo page. Otherwise apache logs must show something.

Comment: Yes, there is offline refund option in credit memo. I looked the Magento logs in the FTP but I didn't see anything there. I will check with our hosting company about the apache logs.

Comment: Check this link it might help you in solving the issue. http://www.sharpdotinc.com/magento-authorize-net-refunds/

Comment: Check /var/log/. If nothing there, then enable logging: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/203-troubleshooting-magento/enabling-system-and-exception-logging-in-magento After that go to Payment Methods - > Authourize.net -> Debug: Yes. This should create a separate log file for Authorize.net. When done try doing credit memo again and see if log is created.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro All members already done  master job. I just want to make point that enables log, enable debug option in Authorize.net (ignore if enable), check `_refund` method in `Mage_Authorizenet_Model_Directpost` and do check that `$request= $this->_buildRequest($payment);` `Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet`  `$request` is showing some errors or not?    Also make sure `$request->setXCardNum($payment->getCcLast4());`  you are sending last 4 cc numbers while making refund.  If `$request` is returning proper then pls check `_postRequest` method in `Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet` model.

Comment: Thanks @Same. The code looks right with all pieces you said. And the log is not showing any error...

Comment: Thanks everyone, this is being really weird and everyone had good insights. I guess I will need to buy an extension for Authorize.NET and see if the refund work that way. I will update the post with more information soon.